# VIM: Select a regex, then apply a command

Tags: regex, vim, text

I want to change a large group of identifiers from lower-case to upper-case. I have a file with a number (hundreds or so) of unique identifiers that start with a `q_`. I constructed a regex that defines this match: `(q_\w*)` and now I want to apply the `~` command to make them all upper-case (they are currently lower-case). I feel like VIM is more than capable of doing this but my skill with it is not there yet, can you help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to up-case the entire identifier, for each identifier in the file, use this substitute command:

```
%s/q_\w\+/\U&/g
```

The trick here is `&` in the replacement pattern, which references the entire match. This will substitute e.g. `q_identifier1` with `Q_IDENTIFIER1`.

If you only want to up-case the `q`, then you can use:

```
%s/q_\(\w\+\)/Q_\1/g
```

Now `q_identifier1` will be changed to: `Q_identifier1`

If you want to up-case everything *except* the `q_`, then use:

```
%s/q_\(\w\+\)/q_\U\1/g
```

Now `q_identifier1` will be changed to: `q_IDENTIFIER1`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, this seems to be what I'm looking for, except, for example, I have: q_name_confirm   ->  I want: q_NAME_CONFIRM, with the q still lower-case, thanks

Comment: with that last example, I am getting the error: E486: Pattern not found: q_\(\w+q\)

Comment: yes, removed the second q and it worked great! thanks, also I had to change the '+' to a '*', does that make sense?

Comment: @steve_gallagher changing `+` to `*` also works: `*` means _zero or more_ and `+` means _1 or more, but at least 1_, which is probably closer to your intent, i.e. a regex that won't match just `q_`. Before my edit, my regex didn't escape the `+`, which was probably causing your problem. See edit: escaped with: `\+`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a macro for this purpose:

- search your pattern: `/q_\w*`
- start recording a macro: `qq`
- make uppercase and find next: `llve~n`
- stop recording your macro: `q`
- repeat as neccessary: `666@q`

but nothing more or it will wrap and change back to lowercase (or alternatively you can turn off `wrapscan` or `ignorecase` temporarily).